# Can objects be created without referencing a specific class like done below?

Tags: java, class, object

In this snippet of code `Object obj = new Object();` an object "obj" is created without following the conventional `"ClassName objName = new ClassName();"`  convention I have seen mostly working with classes. I'm quite new to Java and don't understand how this works exactly without outputting a Compile-Time Error or something.

```
public class Sample {
    public void writeMe(Object obj){
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    public void writeMe(String s){
        System.out.println("String");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Sample s = new Sample();
        Object obj = new Object();
        s.writeMe(obj);
    } 
}
```

Can objects be instantiated using such syntax or is this a specific use case?

Comment: It does follow the `ClassName objName = new ClassName();` convention. In this case, the class name is [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), which is a specific class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object obj = new Object(); 

ClassName objName = new ClassName();
```

These follow the same pattern.  `Object` is the name of a class, just as `ClassName` is.  After the above, `obj` refers to an object of class `Object`; `objName` refers to an object of class `ClassName`.

`Object` happens to be built into the language, and it happens to be the ancestor of all other classes, but neither of those facts are germane to the syntax of those declarations.

Comment: So could I per se write something like `Banana apple = new Banana();` without actually having a class named `Banana{}`?

Comment: @SomilVarshney: No.  You could not.

Comment: @LouisWasserman so I guess the fact that Object is a superclass has something to do with it? Also, why does something like `Object obj = new String();` compile without any errors?

Comment: The only thing relevant here is that Object is [**an actual class**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).  That is is an ancestor of every class would allow you to write `Object o = new ClassName()`.